# Discord Roblox bot

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, roblox

I'm trying to make a command that outputs players collectibles and summarizes the total `recentAveragePrice` of the listed items. The problem is when I'm trying to output any part of this API, it just outputs `undefined`.

API URL:
https://inventory.roblox.com/v1/users/1417341214/assets/collectibles?assetType=Hat&sortOrder=Desc&limit=100

```
if (command === "inv"){
    let getInv = async () => {
        let response = await axios.get("https://inventory.roblox.com/v1/users/1417341214/assets/collectibles?sortOrder=Asc&limit=100");
        let inv = response.data;
        return inv;
    }
    let invValue = await getInv();
    console.log(invValue);
    message.channel.send(`${invValue.data.name} \n ${invValue.data.recentAveragePrice}`);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the returned data is an array of objects. If you want to send them all as a message, you can iterate over them. If you want to send them one by one, the following will work:

```js
if (command === 'inv') {
  const getInv = async () => {
    const response = await axios.get(
      'https://inventory.roblox.com/v1/users/1417341214/assets/collectibles?sortOrder=Asc&limit=100',
    );
    return response.data;
  };
  const invValue = await getInv();
  let total = 0;
  invValue.data.forEach((item) => {
    message.channel.send(`${item.name} \n ${item.recentAveragePrice}`);
    total += item.recentAveragePrice;
  });
  message.channel.send(`Total average price: ${total}`);
}
```

Result:

[image]